# Is a fact a proposition?

Tags: logic, terminology

For example:

The square root of 81 is 9.

Is this a proposition? I ask this because a proposition is where is it is meaningful to ask whether a statement is true or false but in this case it would always be true.

If it is a proposition, would it be a tautology, since 9 is the square root of 81?

Comment: See [Propositions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/): "Propositions, we shall say, are the sharable objects of the attitudes and the primary bearers of truth and falsity. This stipulation *rules out* certain candidates for propositions, including thought- and utterance-tokens, which presumably are not sharable, and concrete *events or facts*, which presumably cannot be false."

Comment: Yes, it is a proposition (in the sense of elementary logic) and a true one and it is not a *tautology*. See [Tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)).

Comment: But the link said that it rules out candidates for propositions which cannot be false aka facts @Mauro ALLEGRANZA

Comment: Nevertheless, if mathematicians speak of "propositions" they do not mean such trivial true statements, rather something like "there are infinite many primes".

Comment: Okay but is ‘the square root of 81 is 9’ a proposition or not? I am confused? @Peter

Comment: It is a provable statement, so technically a proposition.

Comment: ‘All bachelors are unmarried men’ would this be a tautology? @Peter

Comment: Yes, since the definition of a bachelor is an unmarried man. So we have : "All unmarried men are unmarried men" , a clear tautology.

Comment: See [Formal definition of proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795307/formal-definition-of-proposition) as well as [Sentence vs proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232232/sentence-vs-proposition)

Comment: $\sqrt{81} = 9$ is a proposition with truth value $T$. On the other hand, $\sqrt{100}=9$ is also a proposition, but its truth value is $F$.

Comment: "The square root of 81 is 9" in propositional logic is simply $p$ and thus you are right: it is **not** a tautology (according to the propositional logic definition). A tautology of prop logic must have a specified "logical form", like e.g. $p \to p, \lnot p \lor p$ and similar. A single prop variable will never be a tautology (or contradiction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The square root of $81$ is $9.$

In symbols: $$\sqrt{81}=9.$$ Yes, this is a statement, and it is clearly true (based on the conventional interpretation of the various symbols contained in the statement).

Notice that it contains no logical connective (and, or,
conditional, negation, etc.); this means that it is an *atomic statement*; we might further symbolise this proposition as $P.$

> a statement is true or false but in this case it would always be true. If it is a proposition, would it be a tautology

[image]

The truth table on the right shows that the compound statement $\;(A\land B)\to A\;$ is true regardless of what the atomic statements $A$ and $B$ stand for. In other words, $\;(A\land B)\to A$'s *truth-functional form* is always true. This means that $\;(A\land B)\to A\;$ is a **tautology**.

On the other hand, notice that if $P's$ meaning changes to "pigs can fly", or if we reinterpret the $\sqrt{\quad}$ symbol to output the negative root instead of the conventional positive root (so that $\sqrt{81}=9$ becomes false), then $P$ becomes a false statement (corresponding to the bottom row of $P$'s truth table). Since $P$'s truth table contains at least one 'false' entry, $P$ is patently not a tautology: its truth-functional form is not always true. In fact, *no atomic statement can be a tautology*.

In propositional logic, a **tautology** can also be understood as a proposition that is *true regardless of its atomic propositions' assigned meanings*.

---

**Addendum** to address the OP's follow-up questions

1. *can a propositional variable be a tautology, like $\sqrt{81}=9?$ since it would always be true*

Your confusion stems from referring to $\sqrt{81}=9$ as “*always* true”, and conflating this with your impression that tautology means “always true”.

Firstly, ‘$\sqrt{81}=9$’ is not a propositional variable, just as ‘Pigs can fly’ isn't. However, both can be symbolised as the propositional variable $P.$

Secondly, *before continuing any further,* please re-read the third-from-last and last paragraphs of my above Answer.

Notice that asking whether a statement is a tautology involves inspecting its truth table, which requires the statement to first be symbolised in terms of propositional variable(s).

(Clearly then, a single propositional variable by itself cannot be a tautology.)

When considering whether $\sqrt{81}=9$ is a tautology, we are ignoring its particular guise, and considering just its abstract logical skeleton $P$ (as $P$'s assigned meaning varies).

The *truth-functional form* (logical skeleton $P$) of $\sqrt{81}=9$ is not always true; therefore, it is not a tautology. (In fact, $\sqrt{81}=9$ itself can be false, for example when working in base $12.)$ Calling $\sqrt{81}=9$ “always” true is not instructive; better to think of it as just “true”.

In contrast, $$1=1\to\big(1=1\:\lor\:2=3\big)$$ is a tautology.

2. *Or are tautologies only restricted to formulas?*

Do you mean to ask whether tautologies are restricted to only compound propositions? Yes, they are.

Comment: wait I'm a little confused. Propositional variables cannot be tautologies right? Only a formula can be a tautology?

Answer (score 3):

In formal logic, a proposition is anything that's grammatically a *statement* (an expression that has or can have a truth value) as opposed to a *term* (an expression that refers to an object in the domain of discourse, like a number). So yes, $\sqrt{81}=9$ is certainly a proposition. The "actual" truth value of a statement has no bearing on whether it's a proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't overthink this. When in logic we talk about propositions, all we want to say is that it is something for which it makes sense to say that it is true or false.

Examples of propositions: Grass is green. Clark Kent is Superman. I have a billion rollers in my pocket. $\sqrt{81}=9$. $A\subseteq A$.

Examples of non-propositions: Can you open the window? Ouch!! Blubber. Ointment! $42$.

Comment: thank you i get it now. But i just wanted to ask, can a propositional variable be a tautology, like √81=9? since it would always be true. Or are tautologies only restricted to formulas?

Comment: @stevenoakman Two comments on that. First, I do not consider $\sqrt{81}=9$ to be a tautology … it is certainly true in our ‘universe of arithmetic’, but it is not a *logical* truth. Second, even if we consider such logical truths as $9=9$, from the perspective of *propositional * logic, tgat would still be treated as an atomic statement (propositional logic does not gave the power to dig inside such a statement, and so will treat it as some propositional variable $P$. Thus, $9=9$ is not a tautology according to propositional logic. More powerful logics can recognize it as such.

Comment: @stevenoakman: An arithmetical truth like $1+2 = 2+1$ is not a tautology because its truth is dependent on our interpretation of the symbols. An FOL tautology must be true **for every FOL interpretation**. As for $9=9$, "$9$" is a constant-symbol and "$c=c$" is actually an FOL tautology for any constant-symbol $c$.