# Which definition of Proposition is correct in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

So I've come across two different definitions for a proposition,

**1.** A proposition is a sentence that ***can be***
true or false. However, not both simultaneously.
**2.** A proposition is a sentence that ***is*** true or false. However, not both simultaneously.

Let's consider the following sentence,

**5x = 20**

According to the **1st** definition this **is** a proposition since it **can be** either true or false depending on the value of x.

According to the **2nd** definition this **is not** a proposition because we don't know the value of x, so we don't know whether it's true or not.

Which of these is the correct definition?

**Warning:** English is not my first language, so it could be that I understood these definitions incorrectly.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232232/sentence-vs-proposition)

Answer (score 0):

Many textbooks will use the second definition and, consequently, consider $5x=20$ not to be a proposition.

Personally, I am more with the first definition, and say that

> $5x=20$

is a proposition.

Here are some other examples:

> "It rains"

I would say that's a pretty clear proposition. Is it true or false? No idea. Depending on where and when we are evaluating it, I suppose.

Even something like

> $1+1=2$

Sure, this is true in the 'normal' world of mathematics, but I can define different mathematical worlds where this is false.

In short: the truth- or falsity of a proposition depends on what world we are evaluating it in. But it's still a proposition. Unlike things like:

> "It's"

or

> "raining"

or

> $5x$

or

> $=2$

That is, I would say the class of expressions "1+1=2", "5x=20", and "It rains" is quite clearly different from the class of expressions like "1", "rains", and "=", and I would consider the former the class of propositions, and the latter non-propositions

Comment: Hey, thank you. I was thinking the same.